# Shared resource in asio coroutine

Tags: coroutine, asio, c++-coroutine

I have some code like the following and want to prevent concurrent access to a shared resource using asio without using an explicit mutex or lock.

```cpp
asio::io_context context(1) // This indicates to use a single thread.
std::set<int> sharedResource;

asio::awaitable<void> coro1()
{
    co_await someAsyncFunction();
    if (someCondition)
    {
        sharedResource.erase(someElement);
    }
}

asio::awaitable<void> coro2()
{
    for (auto shared : sharedResource)
    {
        co_await someOtherAsyncFunction();
        // /!\ Problem here, how to make sure the implicit range loop iterator
        // was not invalidated by coro1()
    }
}

asio::co_spawn(context, coro1(), asio::detached);
asio::co_spawn(context, coro2(), asio::detached);
```

Tried using an explicit strand even if an io_context with 1 (single threaded) is already supposed to use a strand under the hood, but I still got a segmentation fault due to accessing an invalid iterator.

```cpp
asio::io_context context(1);
auto strand = asio::make_strand(context);

...

asio::co_spawn(strand, coro1(), asio::detached);
asio::co_spawn(strand, coro2(), asio::detached);
```

Comment: I need more context. What are you trying to achieve? Why co_await for someOtherAsyncFunction? I fear an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), Why not simply call someOtherAsyncFunction synchronous, or then co_spawn it detached? Is this a queue? Why not use a deque? Exactly once? What happens if the element processed is deleted? Why not just copy the whole container then at start?